# How to understand the computed width of the block containing `white-space: pre;` with/without `float`?

Tags: css

As you can see the code below, `div` is the outermost scrolling container and the core in this topic `section` is a containing block with `span`s set as `white-space: pre;`.

One `section` is extremely simple and is just a block. The other `.floated` is set `float: left;`.

But the computed width of them is different: the **former** is just as wide as its **containing block** `div` i.e. `100px` in this case, in contrast to the **latter** is as wide as its **contents**, around `1287.47px`(given by Firefox). To make this difference more observable, I set a background color for both of them.

So the question comes:

1. My understanding is that the width of a block with `width: auto;` depends on its contents. Why is the first `section` **not**?
2. The expected effect is achieved by using `float: left;`, as `.floated` shows, but **why** and **how** does it work? What exactly does the `float` do? A new BFC? But if I change `float` to `display: flow-root;` which also creates a new BFC, it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  background-color: teal;
}

span {
  white-space: pre;
}

.floated {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div>
    <section>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis quis earum totam sequi, optio iusto neque sed! Reiciendis fugit, dolor.</span>
      <span>Molestias consequuntur ipsam quod eligendi, temporibus a quos accusamus aliquid molestiae est blanditiis voluptatibus minus ipsum nisi odio tempora sed!</span>
      <span>Suscipit, similique. Dolor possimus non doloribus voluptatibus necessitatibus, quas, consequatur hic provident quo neque sequi? Nesciunt, ratione laudantium rem quis!</span>
      <span>Voluptate delectus, quis laboriosam animi esse, et perspiciatis, cupiditate, porro itaque officiis laudantium quidem. Quos culpa facilis, nesciunt itaque officiis.</span>
      <span>Expedita ex error a explicabo deserunt, consectetur illum quod veritatis. Odio pariatur quae minima quasi, minus itaque architecto illo delectus.</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <section class="floated">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis quis earum totam sequi, optio iusto neque sed! Reiciendis fugit, dolor.</span>
      <span>Molestias consequuntur ipsam quod eligendi, temporibus a quos accusamus aliquid molestiae est blanditiis voluptatibus minus ipsum nisi odio tempora sed!</span>
      <span>Suscipit, similique. Dolor possimus non doloribus voluptatibus necessitatibus, quas, consequatur hic provident quo neque sequi? Nesciunt, ratione laudantium rem quis!</span>
      <span>Voluptate delectus, quis laboriosam animi esse, et perspiciatis, cupiditate, porro itaque officiis laudantium quidem. Quos culpa facilis, nesciunt itaque officiis.</span>
      <span>Expedita ex error a explicabo deserunt, consectetur illum quod veritatis. Odio pariatur quae minima quasi, minus itaque architecto illo delectus.</span>
    </section>
  </div>
```

[Online Demo](https://jsbin.com/nezirareya/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that the width of a block with width: auto; depends on its contents.

It doesn't. The width of a block level element should respect [this formula](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth):

> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block

As you can see, the content play no role in defining the width of your element and it will end with a width equal to its containing block (parent element). That's why you have the logical result of `100px`. After defining the width, the content should try to fit that width but you have disabled line breaks with `white-space: pre` so all you will get is an overflow.

When, you make the div floated you need to consider another part of the Specification that describe [the width of floating elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#float-width) and you can read:

> If 'width' is computed as 'auto', the used value is the "shrink-to-fit" width.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`.

The content is considered in the "shrink-to-fit" algorithm.

In your case, since you are using `white-space: pre` you are not allowing any  line break so the "preferred minimum width" will be the winner and you will end have a width equal to the longest sentence

If you disable the `white-space`, you will force line breaks and your content will try to fit the "available space" and both cases will give the same result even if we have different algorithm involved

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  background-color: teal;
}


.floated {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <section>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis quis earum totam sequi, optio iusto neque sed! Reiciendis fugit, dolor.</span>
      <span>Molestias consequuntur ipsam quod eligendi, temporibus a quos accusamus aliquid molestiae est blanditiis voluptatibus minus ipsum nisi odio tempora sed!</span>
      <span>Suscipit, similique. Dolor possimus non doloribus voluptatibus necessitatibus, quas, consequatur hic provident quo neque sequi? Nesciunt, ratione laudantium rem quis!</span>
      <span>Voluptate delectus, quis laboriosam animi esse, et perspiciatis, cupiditate, porro itaque officiis laudantium quidem. Quos culpa facilis, nesciunt itaque officiis.</span>
      <span>Expedita ex error a explicabo deserunt, consectetur illum quod veritatis. Odio pariatur quae minima quasi, minus itaque architecto illo delectus.</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <section class="floated">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis quis earum totam sequi, optio iusto neque sed! Reiciendis fugit, dolor.</span>
      <span>Molestias consequuntur ipsam quod eligendi, temporibus a quos accusamus aliquid molestiae est blanditiis voluptatibus minus ipsum nisi odio tempora sed!</span>
      <span>Suscipit, similique. Dolor possimus non doloribus voluptatibus necessitatibus, quas, consequatur hic provident quo neque sequi? Nesciunt, ratione laudantium rem quis!</span>
      <span>Voluptate delectus, quis laboriosam animi esse, et perspiciatis, cupiditate, porro itaque officiis laudantium quidem. Quos culpa facilis, nesciunt itaque officiis.</span>
      <span>Expedita ex error a explicabo deserunt, consectetur illum quod veritatis. Odio pariatur quae minima quasi, minus itaque architecto illo delectus.</span>
    </section>
  </div>
```